# ODBC parameter max length 1999 when should be 4000

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, odbc

I am trying to do a simple query from a table using ODBC, c# and Sql Server 2000/2005/2008

Given the following table:

```
create table users ( 
    name nvarchar(50)
)
```

If I run the following:

```
insert into users select 'Administrator'
```

I should have 1 record in the db with 50 a's.
Then I try to run the following select from c#.

```
using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(connstr))
{
    conn.Open();
    var comm = conn.CreateCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "select name from users where name = ?";

    var par = comm.CreateParameter();
    par.Value = "Administrator";
    par.Size = 2000;  //So that query plan is cached
    comm.Parameters.Add(par);

    Console.WriteLine(comm.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

This gives the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The data types nvarchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator.

If I change the DbType to DbType.StringFixedLength it works fine and this same code works fine if using the native driver.

The only way this will work is if the string is less than 2000. Can't be 2000.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the field is not set to `TEXT`?  Sounds like `varchar(max)` is what you want.

Comment: Did you see the table definition above?? this is a repo.

Comment: Did you try setting the type of the parameter explicitly (possibly, *before* assigning the value, too)?

Comment: @AndriyM Yep..as soon as you set the value to 2000 or more you get the error.

Comment: Easy to reproduce but what is your question for us? Just look at the sqlserver profiler and you'll see that it will pass the param as a NTEXT. I expect it is probably an artifact from the old days and would not be surprised if MS would call this 'by design'. If you really want to know you should file a bug report with them.

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly question the design of your database, you can get out of this problem quick and dirty by changing the `=` to `LIKE`